# Enable touch-scrolling in Firefox

Tags: linux, firefox, scrolling, touchscreen

In Firefox, swiping on the touch screen results in selecting text, instead of scrolling (like on an iPad). Is it possible to change the behaviour, so that the touch screen can be used to scroll, while the mouse can be used to select text?

In Chrome, the behaviour is as expected (swipe to scroll, (mouse)drag to select).

I'm using Firefox 50.0 on Linux Mint 18 (based on Ubuntu 16.04). I have dom.w3c_touch_events.enabled set to 2, setting it to 1 does not help either.

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 42):

1. Edit `/etc/security/pam_env.conf` and add this line:

   ```
    MOZ_USE_XINPUT2 DEFAULT=1
   ```
2. Log out and in again

see https://askubuntu.com/a/994483/34298

Comment: thanks, this is the only that worked for me for firefox 70

Comment: super! Thanks! I can confirm this works on Xubuntu 20.04 on a T460s Thinkpad.

Comment: Thanks! I confirm this works on Ubuntu 20.04 on a T440 Thinkpad.

Comment: Thanks! Worked on Debian 11.

Comment: Thanks! Worked on Ubuntu Mate 20.04.4 LTS Focal Fossa for GPD Pocket 2

Comment: I'm happy to report that it still works on Firefox 100.0 on my ThinkPad X280 running Void Linux.

Comment: Outstanding! Worked for me on Arch, Zen kernel, Gnome DE.

Comment: Worked for me on Ubuntu 22.04.1 & Firefox 103.0.2. Thanks!

Comment: Worked on ubuntu 22.04 and XFCE and  Firefox 112. This is the only solution that worked

Comment: This sent me in the right direction but *why* would you set the environment variables there instead of pretty much anywhere else, like the desktop environment or the `.desktop` file?

Answer (score 37):

I finally found a solution: start firefox with:

```
env MOZ_USE_XINPUT2=1 firefox
```

This enables touch-scrolling for me. Pinch-to-zoom does not work for regular web pages, but it does work on some selected web pages such as Google Maps or OpenStreetMap.

Comment: does not work for me using v 51.0.1 (64-bit)

Comment: More detail here: https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1268599#c10

Comment: @ShimonRura thx, xsetwacom --set {id} Gesture off, helped!

Comment: Thank you, that helped me as well!
Use `xsetwacom --list devices` to figure out the id of your touch device.
See also https://github.com/linuxwacom/xf86-input-wacom/wiki/Multitouch

Comment: It seems to have changed. now this is the solution: https://askubuntu.com/a/994483/34298

Comment: For Firefox 77 it worked on Xubuntu 20. I added the env variable to `/etc/environment` so that it's automatically set when starting firefox from the desktop or task bar shortcut.

Comment: On the ChromeOS Debian VM this works while the solution from @rubo77 had no effect.

Comment: I was using ScrollAnywhere which had tons of limitations (like not working in the integrated PDF reader and interfereing with text selection). Very happy that I discovered this, thanks a lot! I wonder why this isn't controllable from Firefox' settings dialog...

Answer (score 6):

Firefox supports touchscreen properly when running in wayland mode, however currently that must be enabled manually.

You can check if you are running firefox in `wayland` mode or `xwayland` mode by going to `about:support` and scrolling to "Window Protocol"

If you are in xwayland mode, you can tell firefox to use wayland mode instead by setting `MOZ_ENABLE_WAYLAND=1` in your environment variables.

If firefox is installed as a flatpak, run this (you might need root if installed system-wide):

```
flatpak override --env=MOZ_ENABLE_WAYLAND=1 org.mozilla.firefox
```

Otherwise if firefox is installed through repo packages, you should add the following line to `/etc/security/pam_env.conf`:

```
MOZ_ENABLE_WAYLAND DEFAULT=0 OVERRIDE=1
```

Comment: Verified the pam_env.conf change works on Ubuntu 22.04 with default Firefox (snap). You would need to reboot the system after the changes for this to take effect.

Answer (score 4):

Just updating with the new format in `/etc/security/pam_env.conf` --now variables must be defined with a default value (which can be empty, "") and an override value (which can be empty, "").

Add the environmental variable like this:

```
MOZ_USE_XINPUT2 DEFAULT=0       OVERRIDE=1
```

Comment: Verified the pam_env.conf change works on Ubuntu 22.04 with default Firefox (snap). You would need to reboot the system after the changes for this to take effect.

Answer (score 1):

With the latest Firefox 84.0.2 it works for scrolling without the risk of getting zoom while scrolling for both vertical and horizontal movements. Zoom works well on most pages with finger/thumb pinch/expand including Google Maps. Select is now activated, as on a mobile, by touch for a second or so then using the select markers. Touch and hold the selection to get the context menu for copy and cut/paste if text is editable. Better functionality than Chrome where the select markers cannot be adjusted from a single word selection!

My screen was detected as a "Wacom 5113 finger" under KDE Plasma 5.2 Manjaro/Arch Linux. I set KDE Wacom touch control panel "gestures off" otherwise weird things start happening on scroll.

Simply edit /etc/security/pam_env.conf and add `MOZ_USE_XINPUT2 DEFAULT=1` then reboot.

The only loss seems to be drag items do not drag with finger input but will still work by mouse/touchpad.

Comment: Verified the pam_env.conf change works on Ubuntu 22.04 with default Firefox (snap). You would need to reboot the system after the changes for this to take effect.

Answer (score 0):

Open up terminal and paste this command

> echo export MOZ_USE_XINPUT2=1 | sudo tee /etc/profile.d/use-xinput2.sh

Comment: An explanation will be welcome.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Can it be inside `.bashrc`?